# How to convert floating point number to integer?

Tags: bash, numeric-data, floating-point

Is this the right way to do float to integer conversion in bash? Is there any other method?

```
flotToint() {
    printf "%.0f\n" "$@"
}
```

Comment: What is "right"?

Comment: I just want to make sure.. is this right or is there better than this ?

Comment: `%.0f` will round up or down. Is that what you want? You can use `printf "%d\n" "$@" 2>/dev/null` to chop the fraction.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

### bash

In `bash`, that's probably as good as it gets. That uses a shell builtin. If you need the result in a variable, you could use command substitution, or the `bash` specific (though now also supported by `zsh`):

```
printf -v int %.0f "$float"
```

You could do:

```
float=1.23
int=${float%.*}
```

But that would remove the fractional part instead of giving you the nearest integer and that wouldn't work for values of `$float` like `1.2e9` or `.12` for instance.

Also note the possible limitations due to the internal representation of floats:

```
$ printf '%.0f\n' 1e50
100000000000000007629769841091887003294964970946560
```

You do get an integer, but chances are that you won't be able to use that integer anywhere.

Also, as noted by @BinaryZebra, in several `printf` implementations (bash, ksh93, yash, not zsh, dash or older version of GNU `printf`), it is affected by the locale (the decimal separator which could be `.`, `,` or `٫`).

So, if your floats are always expressed with the period as the decimal separator and you want it to be treated as such by `printf` regardless of the locale of the user invoking your script, you'd need to fix the locale to C:

```
LC_ALL=C printf '%.0f' "$float"
```

With `yash`, you can also do:

```
printf '%.0f' "$(($float))"
```

(see below).

### POSIX

```
printf "%.0f\n" 1.1
```

is not POSIX as `%f` is not required to be supported by POSIX.

POSIXly, you can do:

```
f2i() {
  LC_ALL=C awk -- '
    BEGIN {
      for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++)
        printf "%.0f\n", ARGV[i]
    }' "$@"
}
```

Note that though literal numbers in the `awk` language syntax are always using the `.` as decimal radix character (as `,` is used to separate arguments so couldn't be used in numbers), when taking numbers on input like here from `ARGV`, some implementations honour the locale's decimal radix character. In the case of GNU `awk`, that's only when `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment.

### zsh

In `zsh` (which supports floating point arithmetic (decimal separator is always the period)), you have the `rint()` math function to give you the nearest integer as a float (like in `C`) and `int()` to give you an integer from a float (like in `awk`). So you can do:

```
$ zmodload zsh/mathfunc
$ i=$(( int(rint(1.234e2)) ))
$ echo $i
123
```

Or:

```
$ integer i=$(( rint(5.678e2) ))
$ echo $i
568
```

However note that while `double`s can represent very large numbers, integers are much more limited.

```
$ printf '%.0f\n' 1e123
999999999999999977709969731404129670057984297594921577392083322662491290889839886077866558841507631684757522070951350501376
$ echo $((int(1e123)))
-9223372036854775808
```

### ksh93

ksh93 was the first Bourne-like shell to support floating point arithmetic. ksh93 optimises command substitution by not using a pipe or forking when the commands are only builtin commands. So

```
i=$(printf '%.0f' "$f")
```

doesn't fork. Or even better:

```
i=${ printf '%.0f' "$f"; }
```

which doesn't fork either but also doesn't go all the trouble of creating a fake subshell environment.

You can also do:

```
i=$(( rint(f) ))
```

But beware of:

```
$ echo "$(( rint(1e18) ))"
1000000000000000000
$ echo "$(( rint(1e19) ))"
1e+19
```

You could also do:

```
integer i=$(( rint(f) ))
```

But like for `zsh`:

```
$ integer i=1e18
$ echo "$i"
1000000000000000000
$ integer i=1e19
$ echo "$i"
-9223372036854775808
```

Beware that `ksh93` floating point arithmetic honour the decimal separator setting in the locale (even though `,` is otherwise a math operator (`$((1,2))` would be 6/5 in a French/German... locale, and the same as `$((1, 2))`, that is 2 in an English locale).

### yash

yash also supports floating point arithmetic but doesn't have math functions like `ksh93`/`zsh`'s `rint()`. You can convert a number to integer though by using the *binary or* operator for instance (also works in `zsh` but not in `ksh93`). Note however that it truncates the decimal part, it doesn't give you the nearest integer:

```
$ echo "$(( 0.237e2 | 0 ))"
23
$ echo "$(( 1e19 | 0 ))"
-9223372036854775808
```

`yash` honours the locale's decimal separator on output, but not for the floating point literal constants in its arithmetic expressions, which can cause surprises:

```
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 ./yash -c 'a=$((1e-2)); echo $(($a + 1))'
./yash: arithmetic: `,' is not a valid number or operator
```

It's good in a way in that you can use floating point constants in your scripts that use the period and not have to worry that it will stop working in other locales, but still be able to deal with the numbers as expressed by the user as long as you remember to do:

```
var=$((10.3)) # and not var=10.3
... "$((a + 0.1))" # and not "$(($a + 0.1))".

printf '%.0f\n' "$((10.3))" # and not printf '%.0f\n' 10.3
```

Comment: `int=${float%.*}` worked very well in my bash (version 3.2.57(1)-release) script on a Mac (version 10.13.4 (17E199)).

Comment: You first formulation fails in GNU bash 4.4.19, e.g.: 
```
$ echo $maximum
32.800
$ printf -v int %.0f "$maximum"
bash: printf: 32.800: invalid number
```

Comment: @LuísdeSousa, your locale probably has `,` as the decimal radix. See the section about `LC_ALL=C`

Comment: Note that this answer answers a different question: *How to remove digits after the dot* not what was asked: *what's the **right** way of doing float to integer*.

Comment: Should this method applied to floats of any number of bits? Should it be the same for a float of 23 bits or 128 bits mantissa?

Answer (score 27):

`bc` - An arbitrary precision calculator language

int(float) should looks like:

```
$ echo "$float/1" | bc 
1234
```

To round better use this:

```
$ echo "($float+0.5)/1" | bc
```

Example:

```
$ float=1.49
$ echo "($float+0.5)/1" | bc 
1
$ float=1.50
$ echo "($float+0.5)/1" | bc 
2
```

Comment: But `float=-2; echo "($float+0.5)/1" | bc` gives `-1`.

Comment: That is called round towards +inf. That is one of [four possible ways to round](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html).

Answer (score 9):

A very simple hacky one is

```
function float_to_int() { 
  echo $1 | cut -d. -f1    # or use -d, if decimals separator is ,
}
```

Sample output

```
$ float_to_int 32.333
32
$ float_to_int 32
32
```

Comment: It'd be possible to use `sed`, but `cut` solution is simpler. I prefer `sed` or `cut` as they are IMHO more available on embedded targets than `awk` (which is still quite common via `busybox` than `bc`).

Answer (score 8):

The previous answer submitted was almost correct: "You could do:

```
float=1.23
int=${float%.*}
```

But that would remove the fractional part instead of giving you the nearest integer and that wouldn't work for values of $float like 1.2e9 or .12 for instance...."

Just use `${float%%.*}`.

```
echo ${float%%.*}
1
```

Comment: The only way `${float%%.*}` could be different from `${float%.*}` would be if `$float` contained more than one occurrence of `.`. That still gives you 1 for 1.99, the empty string for `.12` and 2 for 2.2e9, so it doesn't help at all. Also remember that parameter expansions must be quoted in list contexts in Bourne-like shells.

Answer (score 1):

Related:

1. [how make float to integer in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929848/),
2. [How to round floating point numbers in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167058/)

Complementing [@Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/) `awk` answer:

```bsh
float_to_integer_rounding_nearst() {
    awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<ARGC;i++) printf "%.0f", ARGV[i]}' "$@";
}

float_to_integer_rounding_floor() {
    awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<ARGC;i++) printf "%d", int( ARGV[i] )}' "$@";
}
```

Comment: on my awks, the latter one rounds towards zero, not to minus infinity (as "floor" can be taken to mean). Also, the first rounds halves to even numbers. I'm not sure if that's any different from what Bash's `printf` does, or if there's any other reason to prefer awk over the builtin `printf`.