# Float operations with bc not precise?

Tags: shell, bc, floating-point

When I'm performing float operations in shell using bc, the result is not the same if I use a regular calculator. Am I doing something wrong?

For example, I need to find a volume of a sphere. User inputs the radius value.

```
pi = 3.14

volume=$(echo "scale = 2; (4 / 3) * $pi * ($r ^ 3)" | bc)
echo "Volume is $volume"
```

If radius = 3, unix returns 112.59, and the calculator 113.1.

Comment: `4/3*3.14*(3^3)` should be `36*3.14 = 113.04`, not `113.1` btw. What's that `calculator` you're using?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas one with more digits of pi, it seems. `4/3*3.14159265358979324*(3^3) = 113.09733552923255664` which rounds up to  `113.1`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to understand the meaning of *the scale of an expression* in `bc`. `bc` can do *arbitrary precision* (which doesn't necessarily mean infinite precision) while your *calculator* will probably have the precision of the `float` or `double` data type of your processor.

In `bc`. The *scale* is the number of decimal after the dot, so related to the precision. The *scale* of an expression is determined based on rules that depend on which operator is involved and the `scale` variable (that variable is the one that gives the *arbitrary* dimension of the *precision* of `bc` that is, that can make its precision as big as you want).

For instance, the scale of the result of a division is `scale`. So `4/3` when `scale` is 2 is `1.33`, so a very rough approximation of `4/3`. The scale of `x * y` will be `min(a+b,max(scale,a,b))` (where `a` is the scale of `x` and `b` the scale of `y`), so here `2`. so `1.33 * 3.14` will be `4.17`.

For the rules, you can check the [POSIX specification for `bc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html).

If you want a greater precision, increase `scale`. You can increase it indefinitely. With `bc -l`, `scale` is automatically set to `20`.

```
$ pi='(a(1)*4)' r=3
$ $ echo "(4 / 3) * $pi * ($r ^ 3)" | bc -l
113.09733552923255658339

$ echo "scale=1000; (4 / 3) * $pi * ($r ^ 3)" | bc -l
113.0973355292325565846551617980621038310980983775038095550980053230\
81390626303523950609253712316214447357331114478163039295378405943820\
96034211293869262532022821022769726978675980014720642616237749375071\
94371951239736040606251233364163241939497632687292433484092445725499\
76355759335682169861368969085854085132237827361174295734753154661853\
14730175311724413325296040789909975753679476982929026989441793959006\
17331673453103113187002257495740245517842677306806456786589844246678\
87098096084205774588430168674012241047863639151096770218070228090538\
86527847499397329973941181834655436308584829346483609858475202045257\
72294881898002877683392804259302509384339728638724440983234852757850\
73357828522068813321247512718420036644790591105239053753290671891767\
15857867345960859999994142720979823815034238137946746942088054039248\
86988951308030971204086612694295227741563601129621951039171511955017\
31142218396089302929537125655435196874321744263099764736353375070480\
1468800991581641650380680694035580030527317911271523

$ echo "scale=1; (4 / 3) * $pi * ($r ^ 3)" | bc -l
97.2
```

You can also do all your calculations with a high `scale`, and reduce it in the end for display:

```
$ echo "scale=10; (4 / 3) * $pi * ($r ^ 3)" | bc -l
113.0973355107
$ echo "scale=100; x = (4 / 3) * $pi * ($r ^ 3); scale = 10; x / 1" | bc -l
113.0973355292
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a better value for `pi` and allow the scale to be as is defined by default in `bc` (20 digits):

```
$ echo "r=3; pi=4*a(1); (4/3)*pi*(r^3)" | bc -l
113.09733552923255658339
```

That is a better way to perform the calculation. Scale is a parameter to define the precision used in the calculation, not a parameter to format the numeric output of the result.

To format the number you may use printf:

```
$ result="$(echo "r=3; pi=4*a(1); (4/3)*pi*(r^3)" | bc -l)"
$ printf '%.2f' "$result"
113.10
```

If you get into trouble with the numeric decimal character (`,` or `.`), you may use this version:

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=C printf '%.2f' "$result"
113.10
```

[printf rounds the number following the IEEE 754 implementation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167059/79743)

Of course, you can force bc to cut the decimals with a final change of the scale:

```
$ echo "r=3; pi=4*a(1); res=(4/3)*pi*(r^3); scale=2; res/1" | bc -l
113.09
```

But that is a bad idea in general.