# Convert a float to the next integer up as opposed to the nearest?

Tags: shell, floating-point

The context is there are 2 variables that get divided to a *floating point* result like so:

```
printf "%0.5f\n" $(echo 305/15 | bc -l)
20.33333
```

How can I always round up to the **next** integer i.e. **21**? This is not about rounding up a value above 20.5 to 21 i.e. *nearest* integer. I'm asking because I want a value to be either exactly the integer or the next integer if it's above in whatever way. So how can I evaluate that? With an `if` statement? If I put a *float* there the shell complains it expects an integer. I don't fully understand how to leverage the information in a Q&A such as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89712) to effect a conversion "upward" to the next integer. Something I'm missing?

Comment: It's called the ceiling function. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394988/get-ceiling-integer-from-number-in-linux-bash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `bc` features for that:

```
echo "a=305; b=15; if ( a%b ) a/b+1 else a/b" | bc
```

Comment: Thank you, that [fit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26951796/4256763) in perfectly and helped me quite a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
ceil() {                                                                       
  echo "define ceil (x) {if (x<0) {return x/1} \
        else {if (scale(x)==0) {return x} \
        else {return x/1 + 1 }}} ; ceil($1)" | bc
}
```

Then:

```
$ ceil 5.1
6
$ ceil 5.5
6
$ ceil 5.9
6
```

Comment: Thank you! I like to have such functions handy. I tried it!

Comment: as [noted by @Jane](/a/385175), that gives `6` for `ceil 5.0`.

Answer (score 4):

for positive integers:

```
a=305
b=15
echo $((a%b?a/b+1:a/b))
21
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ksh93` or `zsh`, you can use the `ceil()` function in arithmetic expressions.

In `zsh`, you need to load the `zsh/mathfunc` module first (`zmodload zsh/mathfunc`)

In both `ksh93` and `zsh`, note that for a division to yield a float, you need at least one operands to be a float (otherwise you get an integer division, like in C), so:

```
echo "$((ceil(305. / 15)))"
```

Otherwise `$((ceil(305 / 15)))` would be `$((ceil(20)))`. In `ksh93`, you'll need to change that to `$((ceil(305, / 15)))` if the user's locale indicates that the decimal separator is a comma.

The above outputs `21` in `ksh93`, and `21.` (to make sure it's still a float) in `zsh`. If you want to avoid that trailing `.`, you can convert to integer with:

```
echo $(( int(ceil(305. / 15)) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Through `awk` and add `0.5` to the result then `.f` will round it up to nearest number by itself.

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf("%.f\n", (305/15)+0.5)}' 
21
```

If you want its *floor* function, use `-0.5` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awk [Velour library](//github.com/svnpenn/velour):

```
$ velour -n 'print mt_ceil(305 / 15)'
21
```

Answer (score 0):

Supplement to the answer of cuonglm.

If it shall round negative values down and positive values up,
one can define in addition to `ceil()` as above:

```
ceil2() {                                              
        echo "define ceil2 (x) {if (x/1 == x) {return x} \
        else { if (x<0) {return x/1 -1} \
        else {return x/1 + 1 }}} ; ceil2($1)" | bc
}
```

Edit: I changed if (scale(x)==0) to if (x/1 == x) ;
otherwise 6.0 will be rounded up to 7