# Split input file into X parts of size total lines / X

Tags: shell-script, split, wc, bc

Currently, my bash script splits by number of lines. However, I'd like to split a file into X pieces, each of those having total lines equal to the file length divided by X. The script is run as follows:

```
./script.sh input_file.tsv
```

So far, in the script, I have this:

```
INPUT_FILE=$1
SPLIT_NUM_THREADS=15
TOTAL_LINES=$(wc -l < $INPUT_FILE)
SPLIT_NUM=$( echo "scale=6; $TOTAL_LINES / $SPLIT_NUM_THREADS" | bc)
```

The following issues exist:

- Using $INPUT_FILE to get TOTAL_LINES gets me the error "ambiguous redirect", but using simply "input.tsv" does not. What's wrong there?
- SPLIT_NUM is a float, how do I convert it to an int so it can split by lines?

How can I resolve these issues and split a file by number of pieces?

Comment: I don't get that "ambiguous redirect" error (GNU bash, Version 4.2.53). It appears if an unset or empty variable is used. Please put `echo "$INPUT_FILE"` before the line with the error (though I don't see a possible problem yet).

Comment: Oh FFS I was running the script and forgetting to put the input file in the command, DERP. That's fixed, thank you. All I need to do is get a rounded number for splitting, any idea there?

Comment: Try `SPLIT_NUM=$(expr '(' $TOTAL_LINES + $SPLIT_NUM_THREADS - 1 ')' / $SPLIT_NUM_THREADS )`. There are more compact ways to do this, depending on your shell.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that worked perfectly, thanks so much!

Comment: Maybe you can also make use of something like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168476/44370) for the float part.

Answer (score 2):

Each part gets the integer divide (`$((a/b))`). If the line number modulo the number of parts (`$((a%b))`) is not zero then you have to distribute the spare modulo number over the parts. One solution is to give the modulo value number of parts an additional line.

```
SPLIT_NUM_THREADS=15
TOTAL_LINES=52
for((i=0;i<$((TOTAL_LINES%SPLIT_NUM_THREADS));i++)); do
  echo $((TOTAL_LINES/SPLIT_NUM_THREADS+1))
done
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
for((i=$((TOTAL_LINES%SPLIT_NUM_THREADS));i<SPLIT_NUM_THREADS;i++)); do
  echo $((TOTAL_LINES/SPLIT_NUM_THREADS))
done
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
```